# multiple unpivot and pivot on same column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot, unpivot

I am not sure how can I achieve this output.  In this case, my column is one but the internal value is multiple but I need to merge all and create one unique column header. column "NAME" has multiple values

Please go through with the below problem.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/261454/ignoring-null-values-in-columns-pivot-and-unpivot

Comment: Is the name always the concatenation of the column and row?

Comment: yes. My data warehouse db  return such Name and column header

Comment: try to ask on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you would follow steps like:

create new table, split name into col, row, sort by row, col to create:

```
row  col  data
1    A    Hello
1    B    New
2    A    World
2    B    World
```

then pivot on col and your are done.

```
row  A      B
1    Hello  New
2    World  World
```

does that describe your problem?

Comment: that's what he said, but where's solution?

Comment: I don't see any multiple pivot and unpivot as in the title, so I don't think it this simple. Also there is not enough data to write the split code because It can't be just splitting 2 chars. Pivot code is available here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server